# Find out where Node is freezing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm setting up Passport to authenticate via LDAP (using `passport-ldap`) and whenever a user fails to log in, it successfully loads my `failureDirect` link. However, if I do log in successfully (or so I think) the program just hangs. There aren't any errors received; my browser just seems like it's loading ("waiting for server..."). Is there any way to see exactly where Passport is freezing without going through the entire trace of functions that are called and putting a `console.log` statement in each function?

in my routes:

```
app.post('/users/session',
  passport.authenticate('ldap', {
    failureRedirect: '/login_fail',
    successRedirect: '/admin'
  }), users.session)
```

in my `passport.js` file:

```
var LDAPStrategy = require('passport-ldap').Strategy

[...]

passport.use(new LDAPStrategy({
  server:{
    url: 'ldap://[MY_URL]:3268',
    },
  base: '[HIDDEN]',
  search: {
    filter: "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountname={{username}}))",
    }
  },
  function(user, done) {
    console.log("Success")
    return done(null, JSON.parse(user));
  }
))
```

Comment: we are not telepaths, write some of your code

Comment: I didn't post any code because I didn't assume it was necessary to answer my question. I'll add some now.

Comment: are you sending a response in /admin?

Comment: yeah. i used `passport-local` until yesterday so everything worked right until i changed from `passport.authenticate('local')` to `passport.authenticate('ldap`)` and i don't know why its not working now :(

Answer (score 1):

Node debugger might be a bit verbose. Good old console.error should do the trick. The interface is identical to console.log, but instead console.error blocks until the IO is complete to display the text. This will give you an accurate indication as to where the code died. The only downside is you will have to add a few lines of code like this:

```
console.error( 'debug1' );
console.error( 'debug2' );
console.error( 'debug3' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at this:
http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Node.js debugger. I imagine it would be fairly helpful for stepping through code to find out where it is freezing.

Unless you are seeing freezing in the browser itself, in which case using a standard code inspector should work (Firebug or Chrome Inspector)

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I looked into it but I don't really see any way to just look at what the current function is?

Comment: From what I can tell, you'd want to add a `debugger;` statement right before the block of code you think is having problems, this will cause the debugger to stop at that point (basically a breakpoint). I didn't look much further into the documentation though so I can't give you much more then that.